# React table won't update after rows are added

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate, react-table

I'm trying to create a component to handle mock checkouts (it's called MakeASale).

So far, the main component has a state variable for the list of cart items, and I want to pass those cart items to the cartTable component. So I can show the items on screen as they're added and deleted. The MakeASale component also hosts the functions for adding and deleting.

To support the main MakeASale component, I made child components for the cartTable, and the inventoryModal. And I am passing the addToCart function to the inventoryModal as a prop, so the modal buttons can update the state of cartItems for MakeASale. Then, MakeASale is supposed to update the cartTable when an item is chosen from the modal but it's not recognizing the state change from AddToCart and I'm struggling to figure this out.

Here's what it looks like with the modal closed:

[image]

Here's what it looks like with modal open:

[image]

Issue: When I open the modal and add an item, inventoryModal calls the addToCart function and updates the cartItems in MakeASale. But the CartTable component does not update when that happens. So the item is added to the list, but the table doesn't notice that state change and re-render the cartTable.

The only way I can get the table to update is by typing something into the search bar so that the other stateVariables in MakeASale are updated. Then the table refreshes as well and I'm able to see the changes

Does anyone have advice for making my table update as soon as I click the 'Add to Cart' button from the inventory modal?

Here's my main MakeASale component.

```
const MakeASale = (props) => {
    
    const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = useState("");
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

    const updateSearchFilter = (e) => {
        setSearchFilter(e.target.value);
        console.log(searchFilter);
    };

    const openInventoryModal = () => {
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        modal.style.display = "block";
    };

    const addToCart = (row) => {
        
        if(cartItems.findIndex((current) => current.PID === row.values.PID) >= 0){
            console.log("Cart Item Already Exists");
        }
        else {
            const newCartItem = { ...row.values };
        
            let updatedCartItems = cartItems;
            updatedCartItems.push(newCartItem);
            setCartItems(updatedCartItems);

            console.log(cartItems);
        }
        
    };

    const deleteFromCart = (PID) => {
        
        let updatedCartItems = [...cartItems];

        const deletedIndex = cartItems.findIndex((current) => current.PID === PID);
        updatedCartItems.splice(deletedIndex, 1);
        setCartItems(updatedCartItems);
    };

    return (
        <div className="makeASaleContainer">
            <h1>Make A Sale</h1>

            <section>
                <h2>Live Search:</h2>
                <input type="search" onChange={updateSearchFilter}></input>

                <CompleteInventoryModal uid={props.uid} addToCart={addToCart} />
            </section>

            <div className="makeASale-mainUI">
                <section>
                    <h2>Shopping Cart:</h2>
                    <CartTable2 data={cartItems} deletePID={deleteFromCart} />
                </section>

                <section className="makeASale-GUI-Container">
                    <h2>Controls:</h2>
                    <button onClick={openInventoryModal}>View Full Inventory</button>
                </section>

            </div> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default MakeASale;
```

Here is my InventoryModal

```
const CompleteInventoryModal = (props) => {
    
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    const fetchProducts = useCallback(() => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/request_full_inventory', { 
            uid: props.uid  
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.status === 299){
                console.log(response);
                setProducts([]);
            }
            else{
                console.log(response);
                setProducts(response.data.data);
            }
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error);
        })
    }, [props.uid]);

    useEffect(() => fetchProducts, [fetchProducts]);


    const closeInventoryModal = () => {
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    return (
        <div id="myModal" className="modal">
        
          <div className="modal-content">
            <span className="close" onClick={closeInventoryModal}>&times;</span>
            <p>Complete Inventory Modal..</p>
            <CompleteInventoryTable data={products} addToCart={props.addToCart} />
          </div>
        
        </div>
    );
};

export default CompleteInventoryModal;
```

And here is my CartTable

```
const CartTable2 = (props) => {
    
    const [cartData, setCartData] = useState(props.data);

    useEffect(() => { setCartData(props.data) }, [props.data]);

    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PID</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>SKU</th>
                    <th>Barcode</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody key={cartData}>
                {
                    cartData.map((row) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={row.PID}>
                                <td>{row.PID}</td>
                                <td>{row.pName}</td>
                                <td>{row.sku}</td>
                                <td>{row.barcode}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
};

export default CartTable2;
```

Up until now: I've tried adding useEffect to the cartTable data prop and adding a key to the cartTable's body but none of these are causing the table to re-render.

Comment: The `useEffect` in the `CardTable2` component doesn't seem necessary, you can roll back to using `props.data` in the table directly, instead of a state value from `useState`.
-
Is the component `CompleteInventoryTable ` calling the prop `addToCart` you pass to it?

Comment: @Thalles Cezar you're correct. I have removed that now. But I initially placed that there as an attempted solution.